# Why does electrum need connection to server when recovering a wallet from a seed?

Tags: wallet, electrum, seed

Why does electrum client need connection to server when recovering a wallet from a seed? Isn't the generation of private keys done locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your private information is never shared with the servers and your private keys can always be generated offline.

If you need help doing so, use the #electrum irc channel.

Instructions App:

- Start Electrum
- Select restore
- Enter your seed
- Select 'Cancel' in the server selection
- Enter a password to encrypt your wallet
- Go to settings > Import/Export tab > Private keys: Export

Comment: Oh, funny when I tried it first time it kept waiting for server connection.. I probably did not press cancel on Server selection window but disconnected internet connection instead. Yup. Anyway, it works now. Thanks. My bad. :)

Answer (score 2):

While the generation of the private keys can be locally, to recalculate the account's balance tied to the private keys needs data from the distributed ledger (blockchain). As the electrum client does not keep a replica of the ledger it will need access to recalculate the balance of the accounts and hence of the wallet as a whole.

Comment: I'm aware of that. The point is that the generation of the private keys is not started without connection to server. If, for some reason, I don't have connection to internet or there are no electrum servers running in the future or something other has fundamentally changed, I should always be able to recover my wallet / private keys, so I can transfer them to other client.

Comment: I currently don't see any reason why there should be a reason to require a network connection. So, yes, this ought to be flagged as a defect on the electrum client.

Comment: It is actually possible, I just messed up. :) See [the other answer from rdymac](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/9742/4330) with my comment